# Get event from an iFrame / webview to parent - Ionic

Tags: android, typescript, ionic4

I'm working on an iFrame because I can't make what I want with inAppBrowser or WevView from Ionic.

In fact, I need to get a token from the iframe URL.
The token will be available when the user will click on "Buy".

For this, I just put an iFrame, but I don't know how to detect a click event.

Actually, I want to use another module, like inAppBrowser for example.
But the issue is the same, when we close the window, I can't get the URL.

Here is my actual code (iFrame) :

```
<div class="iframe-content">
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://..." allow="fullscreen" class="iframe-item"></iframe>
</div>
```

When I was working with inAppBrowser, this was my code :

```
const browser = this.iab.create('url', '_self', 'location=yes');
browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => console.log('loadstart :', event));
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => console.log('loadstop :', event));
browser.on('loaderror').subscribe(event => {
    console.log('loaderror :', event);
    this.snackBar.open('Error loading products', 'Ok',
    {
    panelClass: 'snackbar-error',
    duration: 4000
    });
    });
browser.on('exit').subscribe(event => {
    console.log('Exit :', event);    // { type: 'error' }
    console.log('URL :', event.url); // undefinied
});
```